# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext.Type' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObjectContext'

Tags: swift, loops, core-data, error-handling

This is my function:

```
func addtestData() {
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: NSManagedObjectContext) else {
            fatalError("Could not find entity description!")
        }
        for i in 1...25 {
            let device = NSManagedObjectContext(entity: entity, insertIntoNSManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?)
            device.setValue("Some device #\(i)", forKey: "name")
            device.setValue(i % 3 == 0 ? "Watch" : "iPhone", value(forKey: "deviceType"))
            
        }
    }
```

Why is it throwing the following error?

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext.Type' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObjectContext'

Comment: You need to add more details about the context in which you are seeing the error to help you achieve an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the error message:

Both methods related to Core Data expect an **instance** of `NSManagedObjectContext` – according to the naming convention a *variable* starting with a lowercase letter – rather than the **type** `NSManagedObjectContext`

For example in this line:

```
let number : Int = 0
```

`number` is an `Int` instance and `Int` is `Int.Type`

Replace both occurrences of `NSManagedObjectContext` with the instance declared in the Core Data stack, typically `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Thx. I tried this at first but i got a different error, afterwards i changed it as it looks above. Thanks kindly for the answer!